# Haskell / Persistent-Sqlite: "No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadResource IO)"

Tags: database, haskell, yesod

I've been trying to come up with a simple and intuitive way to use databases with Haskell. I've taken this code from the [Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) and tried to clean it up so that it can be easier to understand and use.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite (withSqliteConn, runSqlConn, runMigration)
import Database.Persist.TH (share, mkPersist, mkMigrate, sqlSettings, persist)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persist|
Person                              -- Table name
    name String                     -- String value
    age Int Maybe                   -- Numerical value
|]

updateDB x y = withSqliteConn "data.db" $ runSqlConn $ do
    runMigration migrateAll         -- Creates "Person" table if one doesn't exist
    insert $ Person x $ Just y      -- Inserts values into .db file

main = do
    updateDB "Frank Silver" 40      -- adds name "Frank Silver" and age "40" to data.db file
```

This code *almost* works, but I get the following error which I haven't been able to resolve.

```
No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadResource IO)
      arising from a use of `updateDB'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadResource IO)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: updateDB "Frank Silver" 40
    In the expression: do { updateDB "Frank Silver" 40 }
    In an equation for `main': main = do { updateDB "Frank Silver" 40 }
```

Any suggestions pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You need at least a `runResourceT` around the `updateDB` in `main`. I'm not sure if that will be enough, though.

Comment: rewriting the line as runResourceT $ updateDB "Frank Silver" 40 worked! Thank you. Maybe you'd like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I had this problem using persistent as well, but I also had an error with an instance of MonadLogger for IO missing. I'm leaving it here in the hopes it helps some other poor soul. The key is to use `runResourceT . Control.Monad.Logger.runNoLoggingT`, as the instance for MonadLogger IO has been removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With

```
main = do
    updateDB "Frank Silver" 40
```

the type of `updateDB "Frank Silver" 40` is inferred to be `IO ()`, since that's the default type for `main` (it must have type `IO a` for some `a`). But from the definition, its type is inferred to be `MonadRescource m => m a` for some `a` (probably `a = ()`, but I'm not sure), and there is no `instance MonadResource IO`. So you need something to transform the `updateDB` to an `IO` action, the normal way to do that is `runResourceT`, which transforms a `ResourceT m a` into an `m a` (here `m = IO`), so

```
main = runResourceT $ updateDB "Frank Silver" 40
```

works.

Comment: I've been using Haskell for almost a year and I'm still learning how to use the type system. :D Thanks again for your help and reply.