# Haskell RIO monad inside persistent with pool

Tags: haskell, persistent, conduit, rio

Similar question: [Haskell / Persistent-Sqlite: "No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadResource IO)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047095/haskell-persistent-sqlite-no-instance-for-control-monad-trans-resource-mona)

I'm trying the use the `selectSource` from `persistent` to read the database in streaming mode and log the values in the console using `logInfo`.

The following snippets are executed in a RIO project template.

The following code contains the parts that work and don't work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances       #-}
module Disambiguate.People where

import           Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List       as CL
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.Sqlite
import           Database.Persist.TH
import           Import                  hiding (on, (^.))
import           Prelude                 (print)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int
    deriving Show
|]

disambiguatePeople :: RIO App ()
disambiguatePeople = do
  -- WORKS!
  runSqlite ":memory:" insertAndRead

  -- DOES NOT COMPILE!
  withSqlitePool ":memory:" 1 $ \pool -> do
    liftSqlPersistMPool insertAndRead pool

 where
  insertAndRead = do
    runMigration migrateAll

    insert_ $ Person "John Doe" 35
    insert_ $ Person "Jane Doe" 50

    runConduit $ selectSource [PersonAge >. 5] [] .| CL.mapM_
      (lift . logInfo . displayShow)
```

I get the following error:

```
src/Run.hs:37:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘RIO App’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: ReaderT
                       SqlBackend
                       (monad-logger-0.3.35:Control.Monad.Logger.NoLoggingT
                          (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT IO))
                       ()
        Actual type: ReaderT
                       SqlBackend
                       (monad-logger-0.3.35:Control.Monad.Logger.NoLoggingT
                          (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT (RIO App)))
                       ()
    • In the first argument of ‘liftSqlPersistMPool’, namely
        ‘insertAndRead’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: liftSqlPersistMPool insertAndRead pool
      In the expression: do liftSqlPersistMPool insertAndRead pool
   |
37 |     liftSqlPersistMPool insertAndRead pool
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand the error since the function `liftSqlPersistMPool` hardcoded the `IO` type.

How can I solve this to use it with the `RIO` type ?

Comment: You probably have to apply the environment to the `RIO` action to turn it into an `IO` one. There are probably fancy ways to do this with `MonadUnliftIO` or `MinadBaseControl` or something, but you can also just do it manually.